# Can aggregate functions be used with a variable in the field name?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have some documents that look like this:

```
{
    (...stuff...)
    something: {
        first: {
            0: 3,
            1: 5,
            2: 2
        },
        second: {
            0: 1,
            1: 9,
            2: 7
        }
    }
}
```

For the sake of simplicity in this question, I'll assume that my `$match` only hits this one document. What I'd like to do is, in an aggregate command, add up the `0`s, and add up the `1`s, and add up the `2`s, so that I can produce something like this:

```
something.0:  4   (something.first.0 + something.second.0)
something.1: 14   (something.first.1 + something.second.1)
something.2:  9   (something.first.2 + something.second.2)
```

Is this something that can be done, or do I need to change my document schema to rearrange the nested documents such that all the `0`s are together, etc?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you know the names of all the arrays you want to sum, you can use the Aggregation Framework in MongoDB 2.2+ and a projection with the [`$add` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/#exp._S_add):

```
db.something.aggregate(
    { $project: {
        something: {
            0: { $add: [ "$something.first.0", "$something.second.0" ] },
            1: { $add: [ "$something.first.1", "$something.second.1" ] },
            2: { $add: [ "$something.first.2", "$something.second.2" ] }
        }
    }}
)
```

Sample output:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("517ae4914bc9ade96ca6402d"),
            "something" : {
                "0" : 4,
                "1" : 14,
                "2" : 9
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

If you don't know the names (i.e. you are using trying to add the 0th element of every array element in a document) you will need to use MapReduce or implement the logic in your application code instead.

Comment: I was hoping for something with a wildcard or something, so that I wouldn't have the longest command ever when I add all 24 fields to the something subdocument

Comment: @DiMono: As per the comment at the end of my answer, MapReduce or application logic is probably a more appropriate solution then.  The original question only mentions elements 0/1/2, but if you have 24 fields the Aggregation Framework is going to be rather verbose.  If you are only doing this calculation on a single document (or few documents) it would probably be most efficient to just iterate the documents in your application logic.  If you need to run the calculation against a range of documents, that would favour using MapReduce.

Comment: Of course, you can always build the Aggregation Framework pipeline programmatically so you don't have to write out the 24 fields yourself. This is still overkill for a single document. Depending on how frequently you need to run this query, another option to consider is [pre-aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/use-cases/pre-aggregated-reports/) so you could adjust sums for your nested documents in the same updates that set their values.

Comment: Well, not the answer I wanted, but it seems to be the correct one. Thanks